# Python - MySql query for ip address within cidr range

Tags: python, mysql, ip-address

Ok I need a little bump here. I have a mysql database, within the db, I have a table with ip address stored as inet_aton. I have the ip cidr ranges in the table. Such as 192.168.0.0/24 or /8 etc. I'm using Python to query the db to see if a single /32 ip address is in the db.  I'm trying code like this:

```
def ip_in_networks(ip, networks):

    found_net_type = ''
    found_template = ''


    ip_as_int = unpack('!I', inet_aton(ip))[0]

    for (network, netmask, net_type, template) in networks:


        if (ip_as_int & netmask) == network:

            # we are, awesome
            found_net_type = net_type
            found_template = template
            break
def fetch_networks(r_conn):
    '''This returns a list of networks as [[network, netmask], ...]'''
    nets = []
    r_cur = r_conn.cursor()
    sql = 'SELECT n.network, n.netmask, l.lookup_value, l.template '
    sql += 'FROM network n, lookup l '
    sql += 'WHERE n.network_type_id = l.id'
    r_cur.execute(sql)
    for row in r_cur:
        nets.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]])
    return nets

if __name__ == '__main__':
 ''' some code removed'''

  "connect to the db"
  networks = fetch_networks(r_conn)
  ip = sys.argv[1]

  net_type, template = ip_in_networks(ip, networks)

  if net_type:
    '''If net_type which means found the ip address ini the db, do something, in this case 
       just log the found message''
```

The error I am getting is an Type Error Unpack Non sequence.

I'm trying to stick with standard Python 2.7 library and Mysql.

I'm missing something simple I'm sure. I'd also change my code completely if needed. I have to many IP ranges to just break them out as from this ip address to that ip address and see if the ip is within that range.

Comment: Couldn't you do this all in MySQL? There is the bitwise & operator as well.